# Moving Vue component into separate file cannot be found by main app component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to work with this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yvjoj937x1?fontsize=14) for the NPM Package [vue-fixed-header](https://github.com/potato4d/vue-fixed-header). In the Code Sandbox, the fixed header is in the main `App.vue` file. I'm trying to isolate it to its own file by moving all necessary parts to the `HelloWorld.vue` component inside the `component` directory. After moving everything, the `HelloWorld.vue` file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <VueFixedHeader
    :threshold="propsData.threshold"
    :headerClass="propsData.headerClass"
    :fixedClass="propsData.fixedClass"
  >
    <nav>
      <el-menu>
        <el-menu-item style="pointer-events: none;" index="1">
          Fixed Header
        </el-menu-item>
      </el-menu>
    </nav>
  </VueFixedHeader>
</template>

<script>
  import VueFixedHeader from "vue-fixed-header";

  export default {
    name: 'fixedHeader',
    components: {
      VueFixedHeader,
    }
  }
</script>

...
```

I then try to import this file to be used inside `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <fixedHeader /> <-- tried importing here
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import fixedHeader from './components/HelloWorld' <-- tried importing file here

...
```

This doesn't work though, and Code Sandbox says that `fixedHeader is defined but never used.`

Comment: why filename is `HelloWorld`?

Comment: That's what the file name starts out as in the original Code Sandbox.

Comment: rename it to the name of component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good practice to define vue components with capitalised camel-casing.

1. Change the component name of fixedHeader to FixedHeader (can work without this step)
2. Use it as below:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <fixed-header/> <-- tried importing here
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FixedHeader from './components/HelloWorld'

export default {
  components: {
    FixedHeader
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I still can't get it to work, but I upvoted because I wasn't naming my components like this. I will now. Thanks.

Comment: Check this Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/r4903v5pz4. I've put up a basic import example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <fixedHeader /> <-- tried importing here
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import fixedHeader from './components/HelloWorld' <-- tried importing file here

export default{
  components: {
    fixedHeader,
  }
}
</script>
```